# MAMP Email PHP difficutly

Tags: php, html, email, mamp

I've placed my `.html` file and `.php` file inside the htdocs (MAMP) folder but whenever I click `submit` on the my webpage to test it, it sends me to this error page [image].

I'm not sure why it does that.

HTML code:

```
<form action="pveemail.php" method="POST">
<p>Email Adress: <input type="text" name="email" size="30"></p>
<p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" size="30"></p>
<p>Message: </p>
<p><textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$from = "test@something.com";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);

print "Your message was sent";

?>
```

Comment: Is the email file in the same folder as the HTML file?

Comment: You can't send mail from your local web server, try to use SwiftMailer or PHPMailer to use another SMTP server.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah it is.  I placed both of the files in the htdocs folder.

Comment: Use [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut) to receive mail locally.

Comment: Does MAMP run a `helloworld.php` script? Or is it just the `pveemail.php` what fails?

Comment: @ThijsBouwes That's the issue, I don't know what's failing which is why I posted that screenshot that's appearing on my browser.  Also, I don't think it runs any `.php` script.  I want to test it out locally so that one day I could make the website live and users will allow to send me emails globally, if that makes sense.

Comment: @g24 oké try to echo hello world in a `index.php` if that works, we know php is functional. After that check if php error logging is enabled. Because mail() will throw an Warning (there is no mailserver).